# Swift iframe not loading in web view

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, webview

Basically, in a web view, my page loads fine, but the iframes in it never load, they just stay white or don't appear at all, this happens in both htmlstrings and NSURL sessions please help.
code

```
import Darwin
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var InterfaceX: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sleep(1)

    let url=NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("hi", withExtension: "html")
    //let url = NSURL(string: "http://creepertech.net/xe/interface")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    InterfaceX.loadRequest(request)
    InterfaceX.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;

    //let htm:String! = "<head><header></header></head><body><iframe src=\"http://xegaming.com\"></iframe></body>"
    //InterfaceX.loadHTMLString(htm, baseURL: nil)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var m_objWebView: UIWebView!

func CreateWebViewPlayer()
    { 
     self.m_objWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

     let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"URL HERE\"?playsinline=1\" width=\"320\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

     self.m_objWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
    }
```

NOTE :- Replace URL HERE with your actual URL

Comment: have anything in swift?

Answer (score 1):

Since UIWebView is deprecated, here is the solution in Swift 5 with WKWebView.

Just add a WebKit View to a ViewController in Storyboard and connect the outlet.

```
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"https://YOUR_URL" height=\"500\" width=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" loading=\"lazy\"></iframe></body></html>"
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Vicky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384152/17321403) for the solution! Check her answer to see some more iFrame settings like `scrolling enabled`.