# Displaying HTML text in UITextView crash occurred in swift 4?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, swift4

I am using this code snipped

[image: Code to show HTML Text in TextView]

```
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) // Get crash on this line
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}

var htmlToString: String {
    return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
```

showing `HTML` text in `UITableViewCell`

```
cell.textViewMessage.attributedText = msg.htmlToAttributedString
```

Launching first time there is no crash but after that when I run the code got a crash and not working after that.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

**#Edit HTML String to display in cell**

```
<p>Here\'s a short video tour.  Press play to start.</p><br><iframe class=\"ql-video\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com\"></iframe><br>
```

**#Edit 1 - I am trying to run this code in Playground and it's just working fine except now it's showing an error. Please see the attached image**

[image: Playground output]

Comment: And do you have a crash message in console?

Comment: No. there is no crash message in console. xcode stuck at that code snipped with a red line.

Comment: @Vishal16 may you called it in background?

Comment: @QuocNguyen No, I am calling it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the main thread?

Comment: @Vishal16 seem like some one has problem with background thread. not you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915533/2776008. Can you provide more crash info

Comment: @QuocNguyen I have already said, I am not using it from the background thread? and also there is no crash log in the console?

Comment: @Vishal16 add your html list, because your list  include incorrect html tags

Comment: @a.masri I don't understand. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: do you use html , not attached in your question ?

Comment: Yes, Some time tag come with `<html>.....</html>`.

Comment: In your edit `HTML String to display in cell`, the iframe doesn't contain a video id. Could you give a real example of the data you have in the textView

Comment: @Vishal16 The Grace period of the bounty is almost over 

Comment: @Carpsen90 iframe contains a video id, you can add yours for testing.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I know that bounty is almost over because I am not getting any relevant answer to my problem. ;)

Comment: If my answer is not relevant to your question I’ll remove it. I did add a video id in my example code, the source in your code is `www.youtube.com`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the problem is the tag, not every tag can show up in uitextview.
You can display better these tag in uiwebview

I thinks the problem is iframe tag.

To display iFrame use uiwebview instead, or wkwebview.

Thanks

Comment: I know that already but I need to perform it on `UITextView`?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this issue is the table view, this error will occur very randomly and hard to reproduce because its more specific to device memory and UI draw process which might result in executing the method in the background thread. While reallocating and deallocating the table cells, deep down somewhere the table cells might call this method on a background thread while the HTML importer uses a non-thread-safe WebKit importer and expects to be on the main thread.

**How to reproduce this error:** Run the code using UITest and it will crash more often since the unit test slows down the UI draw process significantly

**Solution**: decode HTML to String should be on the main thread but do this in the model layer on main thread instead of doing it during cell creation. This will make the UI more fluid as well.

**Why the crash was not caught in catch block**: Your app has crashed due to an unhandled language exception, as used by the exception handling infrastructure for Objective-C. SWIFT is like a nice wrapper around Cocoa’s NSError.  Swift is not able to handle Objective-C exceptions, and thus an exception through by Objective-C code in the frameworks will not be caused by your Swift error handler.

Comment: Working with Swift 5.1

In order to make `NSMutableAttributedString` work with `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html`, I needed to run the code into the main queue.

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
      }
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution inspired by [this](https://github.com/ivankoop/IOS-YoutubeTextView) repo. Basically we remove the `iframe` tag and replace it with clickable `img`:

```
let msg = "<p>Here\'s a short video tour. Press play to start.</p><br><iframe class=\"ql-video\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/wJcOvdkI7mU\"></iframe><br>"

//Let's get the video id
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: msg.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "((?<=(v|V)/)|(?<=be/)|(?<=(\\?|\\&)v=)|(?<=embed/))([\\w-]++)")
guard let match = regex.firstMatch(in: msg, options: [], range: range) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find the video ID")
}
let videoId: String = String(msg[Range(match.range, in: msg)!])

//Let's replace the the opening iframe tag
let regex2 = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:
    "<[\\s]*iframe[\\s]+.*src=")

let str2 = regex2.stringByReplacingMatches(in: msg, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "<a href=")

//And then replace the closing tag
let regex3 = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:
    "><\\/iframe>")
let range2 = NSRange(location: 0, length: str2.utf16.count)
let str3 = regex3.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str2, options: [], range: range2, withTemplate: "><img src=\"https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"\(textView.frame.width)\" /></a>")         // You could adjust the width and height to your liking

//Set the text of the textView
textView.attributedText = str3.htmlToAttributedString
textView.delegate = self
```

To open the Youtube app when the user taps and holds on the image, implement this delegate method:

```
extension NameOfYourViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:])
        return true
    }
}
```

If the youtube app is not installed, then the video will be played in Safari.

Here is the result:

[image: Youtube in a UITextField]

Comment: Your solution worked but I am looking for an answer which will resolve my crash log. If no one helped me I will accept yours.

Comment: @Vishal16 From my tests, that error message comes up because javascript can't be enabled in a `UITextField`

Comment: It's a `UITextView`?

Comment: I mean a textView.

Comment: The main problem is that I have surrounded that code with `try-catch` block. Still crash occurs. why?

Comment: @Vishal16 Not executing javascript in a textView is not a crash, it is the normal behavior, so of course there wouldn't be an error to *catch*.

Answer (score 1):

Write in main async is helped me.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 self.myLabel.attributedText = self.myAtributedText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for UITextView:

```
let string = "<h2>The bedding was hardly able to cover it.</h2>"
if !string.isEmpty{
    if let htmlData = string.data(using:String.Encoding.unicode) {
    do {
          let attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
           cell.textViewMessage.attributedText = attributedText
       } catch let e as NSError {
          print("Couldn't translate \(string): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
       }
 }
```

Try this for UILabel for setting html text to uilabel with html tags:

```
extension String {
     var withoutHtmlTags: String {
            let a = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

            return a.replacingOccurrences(of: "&[^;]+;", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
        }
    }

let string = "<h2>The bedding was hardly able to cover it.</h2>"

textUIlabel.text = string.withoutHtmlTags
```

Comment: Do you try it with `<iframe>` tag or video URL?

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959423/swift-iframe-not-loading-in-web-view..here they used <iframe>...i am not familiar to this tag..

Comment: but they are using `UIWebView` and my problem is using `UITextView`?

Answer (score -2):

Changes your options to:

```
let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
                NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
            ]
```